# Call to undefined function session_start()

Tags: php, session, fatal-error

I'm trying to start a session with php, but I always get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_start() in /www/test/test.php on line 2
```

My Code (Copied form http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
  $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
  $_SESSION['count']++;
}
?>
```

In my php.ini I got `extension=session.so` . Further, my settings in session section are:

```
[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "/tmp"
session.use_cookies = 1
;session.cookie_secure =
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor     = 100
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = On
session.bug_compat_warn = On
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
;session.entropy_file = /dev/urandom
session.entropy_file =
;session.entropy_length = 16
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 4
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset="
```

I'm using PHP Version 5.4.17. The server is running on an [Arduino Yun](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardYun) (Linux).

Anyone can help me, or give ma a hint? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Check your error logs and your PHP modules paths.  Just because you're telling PHP to load the sessions extension doesn't mean that it actually exists on your machine.

Comment: You might also run [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to see whether the module is loaded properly.

Comment: check phpinfo() or php -i

Comment: Someone might be a php newbie like me so I'm putting this in.  I checked phpinfo and session support was enabled.  Problem was that I wrote `session.start();` instead of `session_start();`.  I think I'm allowed to simply say "doesn't work" for this one.

Answer (score 11):

I had to install additional [php7-session](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/php7-session) package on Alpine Linux to make it work. I guess you can install it too:

```
opkg install php5-mod-session
```

Comment: Did alpine rename their package manager, or is that a typo? https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management v https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/additional-software/opkg

Comment: I'm using PHP 8 on Alpine, and added the following to my Dockerfile:
`apk add php8-session`
Seems to be working OK.
Thanks for the suggestion @vladkras

Answer (score 3):

On FreeBSD 11:

```
su pkg install php72-session
service php-fpm restart
```

my 2 cents

Answer (score 2):

looks like self-compiled php with `--disable-session` for minimization purpose.
Try to recompile your php without this option.

You can check this in `php -i` output.
Should be `Session support => enabled`

Answer (score 2):

If you are running PHP cli version from a shell, the session extension is not included because it does not make sense, as sessions only exist when the user is accessing your server via a Web browser.